# PyPdf python encode method

Tags: python, pdf, ascii, encode, pypdf

```
text = getPDFContent(path).encode("ascii", "ignore")
```

This is my actual code. Can anyone tell me what does ignore do? And if there's an another parameter for don't copy non-ascii chars?
(I copied the function. It is used to get the contents of a pdf)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at the documentation? The second argument to the `encode` method on a string object indicates how errors are handled.